# Как обновить несколько редюсеров из одного action?

Tags: reactjs, redux

вот например есть в меня action

```html
export const updateChanged = (object) => {

  return {type: 'UPDATE_CHANGED', payload: object}

}
```

он обновляет только один редюсер, можно как-то обновить несколько?

Comment: Почему бы не вызвать несколько action creator-ов из одной функции? К примеру: handleClick = (e) => { this.props.sortList(); this.props.searchText(); this.props.filterList() }

Comment: Т.к. reducer это, упрощённо, if инструкция, то будет в один момент выполнен лишь один пункт совпадающий по action.type. Поэтому несколько сразу нельзя выполнить.